# Command Prompt change file icon

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10

It is possible to change file associations using the command prompt

```
assoc .c=Cfile
ftype Cfile="C:\emacs\bin\emacsclient" -n "%1"
```

Is there a way to change the icon of a file this way also. Or is the best way to do this by editing the registry.

I want to make a script or C program to do this so I don't want a icon association program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to do this very easily with the right tools in the windows console, or write a BAT program to do this for you.

First, you need to find the association value.

```
ECHO WHAT ASSOC FILE ICON ARE WE EDITING? 
SET /P VAR=
```

Next, you need provide the icon file path

```
ECHO WHERE IS THE ICON LOCATED? 
SET /P VAR2=
```

Finally, you can write a script to edit this.

That would look like:

```
echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 >>tmp.reg
echo [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\%var%\DefaultIcon\] >>tmp.reg
echo "(Default)"="%var2%" >>tmp.reg
```

than you can run the file with

```
start tmp.reg
```

Comment: Would you please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349348/how-to-assign-an-icon-to-a-file-type-of-a-qt-program-using-a-script-file) please? I'm going to set an icon on a file type using a script file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Reg.exe console tool to write to the registry. For example,

```
reg add hkcr\Cfile\DefaultIcon /ve /d "e:\icons\myicon.dll,0"
```

This sets the DefaultIcon value for Cfile to `e:\icons\myicon.dll,0`